# Apache .htaccess redirect subdomain to parent domain

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect my subdomain

http://xyz.domain.com to http://domain.com

and similarly any subdirectories like

http://xyz.domain.com/abc to http://domain.com/abc

I don't want redirection for all my subdomains but specifically for this one.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [redirect,last]
```

Comment: @Hussain - Changed it. Try again.

Comment: it does work but I had to put the .htaccess file in ht xyz folder. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of redirecting a subdirectory to a domain:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdir/$  http://example.com$1
```