# HTACCESS SubDomains to WWW

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, forwarding

I know there are multiple similar questions out there, but none to which were able to solve my problem.

I am trying to forward all sub-domains to www.
Every code that I have tried, my browser keeps responding, "Opps! could not find".

This is a portion of my HTACCESS file, and hope that some is able to help me find a solution.
Again, I currently don't have any sub-domains setup at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#
# Make sure the domain does use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ca/$1 [L,R=301] 

#
# Trailing slash check
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic here. Ask at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm guessing your browser doesn't say "Opps! could not find". How about you give us the **actual** error message?

Comment: Maybe this will help?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001061/apache-htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-parent-domain][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001061/apache-htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-parent-domain

Comment: @ceejayoz Actually it says (google chrome), "Oops! Google Chrome could not find test.domain.ca"...

Comment: See, that's much more useful. That means you don't have a DNS entry for test.domain.ca. You'll likely need a wildcard DNS entry for *.domain.ca.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, I thought I could get around that. I have done sub-domain stuff before through htaccess (making a folder a sub domain). I thought I could do this the same way.... In cPanel, I created a wildcard sub-domain  ( *.domain.ca -> www.domain.ca ) but it is not recognizing this...

Comment: You still have to create those domains in DNS, and cPanel may need some extra config for a wildcard subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I currently don't have any sub-domains setup at the moment

If they aren't set up, then requests to them will get a DNS error and never get near your web server.

You need to set them up.

Comment: So, check if your DNS provider allows wildcarded CNAMES and set that up.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I thought I could get around that. I have done sub-domain stuff before through htaccess (making a folder a sub domain). I thought I could do this the same way.... In cPanel, I created a wildcard sub-domain  ( *.domain.ca -> www.domain.ca ) but it is not recognizing this...thoughts?