# My htaccess redirect rule is not working for my subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

What I am trying to do is redirect all requests coming from

`blog.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/blog`

Here is what I have tried so far based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001061/apache-htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-parent-domain) on SO:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the RewriteEngine? Make sure you have this somewhere before your .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Without these, Apache's Rewrite engine won't recognize these rules, and won't start parsing them as you expect.